# how to get the records according to date

Tags: mysql

hi i need to get list of records which expiry date is near (i.e if product exp date is 11 dec 2013 and admin given alert for this product is 5 days .Admin will get alert from 6 dec 2013 onwards) below is my table

```
+---------+--------------+-------------------+
|   id    |   due_date   |   reminder_type   |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+
|   1     |  2013-12-11  |    5 day          |
|   2     |  2014-12-11  |    5 month        |
|   3     |  2015-12-11  |    5 day          |
|   4     |  2013-12-19  |    5 day          |
+---------+--------------+-------------------+
SELECT * , CONCAT( 'date_add(NOW( ) ,INTERVAL', reminder_type, ')' ) AS x
FROM `alerts` 
HAVING `due_date` = x
```

i tried the above query but its not working .

Answer (score 0):

Try This. 
and for expired data you can add one more column like active or not active.
Following will order it by closing record according to reminder type and due _date
It looks like very easy query but it works perfectly.

```
SELECT * FROM alerts ORDER BY due_date, reminder_type DESC
```

And If you add one more column init then the query would be :

```
SELECT * FROM alerts WHERE active='Y' ORDER BY due_date, reminder_type DESC
```

By adding column will worth it you can sort out how many of records are expired.

Comment: its not what i need .